# Centrar Options de un Select

Tags: html, css, select

Quiero que las opciones estén centradas , porque aparecen al lado izquierdo.

MI código html:

```css
.formulario__campo {
  background-color: var(--blanco);
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1rem solid var(--gris);
  text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<select class="formulario__campo">
                        <option disabled selected> --Elegir talla-- </option>
                        <option value="">S</option>
                        <option value="">M</option>
                        <option value="">ML</option>
                        <option value="">X</option>
                        <option value="">XL</option>
                    </select>
```

Quiero que las opciones s,m,ml,x,xl estén centradas, ya he intentado así:

```css
.formulario__campo {
  background-color: var(--blanco);
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1rem solid var(--gris);
  text-align-last: center;
}
```

```html
<select class="formulario__campo">
                        <option disabled selected> --Elegir talla-- </option>
                        <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S</option>
                        <option value="">M</option>
                        <option value="">ML</option>
                        <option value="">X</option>
                        <option value="">XL</option>
                    </select>
```

Pero como pueden ver no me da el resultado deseado,pruebenlo en algún navegador y van a ver que se ve diferente, aquí se ve bien, lo que quiero lograr es que el option y el select se vean centrados y no uno diferente al otro.

Answer (score 0):

¿Intentaste usar la propiedad text-align:center en las opciones?

```css
.formulario__campo {
  background-color: var(--blanco);
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1rem solid var(--gris);
  text-align-last: center;
}
.option{
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<select class="formulario__campo">
                        <option disabled selected> --Elegir talla-- </option>
                        <option value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;S</option>
                        <option class="option" value="">M</option>
                        <option class="option" value="">ML</option>
                        <option class="option" value="">X</option>
                        <option class="option" value="">XL</option>
                    </select>
```